# How to suppress console logs of successful unit-tests in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1, xctest

Any failure-log is lost amidst the flood of success-logs such as

```
Test Case '-[TestClass testMethod]' started.
Test Case '-[TestClass testMethod]' passed (0.029 seconds).`
```

How do you disable these success-logs?